# double[]=operator/(double[] a,double[] b) or Vector[]=operator/(Vector[] a, Vector[] b); Why can I not do this? Even just for myself?

Tags: c#, math, operator-overloading

I want to overload math and the array and [] to do mathematical operation

After a lot of up and back, the answer is the design of c# won't let you overload even  for yourself 'build-in' types like you can in c++.

This is subject to a lot of debate and may emerge in the future as a feature.

Old c programmers moving (grudgingly to c#) will demand this. I demand this.

For example, I have lots of derived types for openGL such as Vertex x. I want to add them, make arrays of them, find them. Inherit them into bigger objects such as triangle or quad strips.

Specifically, I want to overload binary operators for =/ accumulator operators.

Below, I answer my question. 
The secret is in C++ you can overload =/ TOKEN. 
=/ is short for a=a/b. the operator =/ is ONE token.

In c# it is TWO tokens, and you can't overload the assignment(=) (use an implicit conversion or an explicit cast), you overload the
operator as a binary second token.

For example:

---

```
class Vertex{
    public float x,y,z;
    public Vertex(){get;set}

    int some_small_int=2;
    Vertex[] A=new Vertex[some_small_int];
    Vertex[] B=new Vertex[some_small_int];
    Vertex[] C=new Vertex[some_small_int];

    public static Vertex[] operator+(Vertex[] A, Vertex[] B)
    {
        Vertex[] C=new Vertex[A.Count()];
        for( int i=0;i< A.Count();i++)
        {
            C[i]=A[i]+B[i];
        }
        return C;
        }
    }
}
```

... insert into Vertex class...

---

```
array Vertex plus(array Vertex A, array Vertex B){
array Vertex C=new array<vertex>[A.Count()]; // B.Count() better be the same.
    for(int i=0;i<A.Count();i++)
    {
        C[i].x=A[i].x+B[i].x;
        C[i].y=A[i].y+B[i].y;
        C[i].z=A[i].z+B[i].z;
    }
}
```

Why can't do this in c#?

Because it is designed that way.  I would have to write a class Float (as a wrapper for float).

Comment: Step #1: `struct VertexArray { public Vertex[] items; }`  Step #2: Define operators for `VertexArray` objects.

Comment: Removed C++ tag since your question is about C# (you don't show any C++ code or issues).

Comment: What is `modern c#`, as opposed to `legacy c#` ???

Comment: Modern c# version 6.  Legacy is described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156499.aspx One of the features in version 6 is overload resolution. I don't know if ultimately it was an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole listing for a `Vector3` class in order to get ideas on how to implement operators and indexers.

```
[ImmutableObject(true)]
public struct Vector3 : IEnumerable<float>, ICloneable
{
    readonly float x, y, z;

    #region Definition
    public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;
    }
    public Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
        : this((float)x, (float)y, (float)z) { }

    public Vector3(Vector3 other)
    {
        this.x=other.x;
        this.y=other.y;
        this.z=other.z;
    }
    public Vector3(string description)
        : this()
    {
        FromString(description);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Indexer allows the use of the '[]' operator in Vector3
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The integer index 0-2</param>
    /// <returns>A scalar value</returns>
    public float this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0: return this.x;
                case 1: return this.y;
                case 2: return this.z;  
            }
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
    public float X { get { return x; } }
    public float Y { get { return y; } }
    public float Z { get { return z; } }
    public float Magnitude { get { return Norm(); } }
    public float Norm() { return (float)Math.Sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z); }
    public Vector3 Normalized() { var m=Norm(); if (m>0) return this/m; return this; }
    public static readonly Vector3 O=new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    public static readonly Vector3 I=new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    public static readonly Vector3 J=new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    public static readonly Vector3 K=new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    public static explicit operator float[](Vector3 vector)
    {
        return vector.ToArray();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Math
    public Vector3 Add(Vector3 other, float scale=1)
    {
        return new Vector3(
            x+scale*other.x,
            y+scale*other.y,
            z+scale*other.z);
    }
    public Vector3 Scale(float scale)
    {
        return new Vector3(
            scale*x,
            scale*y,
            scale*z);
    }
    public Vector3 Multiply(Matrix3 rhs)
    {
        return new Vector3(
            X*rhs.A11+Y*rhs.A12+Z*rhs.A13,
            X*rhs.A21+Y*rhs.A22+Z*rhs.A23,
            X*rhs.A31+Y*rhs.A32+Z*rhs.A33);
    }
    public Vector3 Reciprocal(float numerator)
    {
        return new Vector3(numerator/x, numerator/y, numerator/z);
    }
    public static float Dot(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        return v1.x*v2.x+v1.y*v2.y+v1.z*v2.z;
    }
    public static Vector3 Cross(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        return new Vector3(
            v1.y*v2.z-v1.z*v2.y,
            v1.z*v2.x-v1.x*v2.z,
            v1.x*v2.y-v1.y*v2.x);
    }
    public static float AngleBetween(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
    {
        var cos=Dot(v1, v2);
        var sin=Cross(v1, v2).Norm();
        return (float)Math.Atan2(sin, cos);
    }
    public Vector3 AlongX() { return new Vector3(x, 0, 0); }
    public Vector3 AlongY() { return new Vector3(0, y, 0); }
    public Vector3 AlongZ() { return new Vector3(0, 0, z); }
    public Vector3 AlongXY() { return new Vector3(x, y, 0); }
    public Vector3 AlongYZ() { return new Vector3(0, y, z); }
    public Vector3 AlongZX() { return new Vector3(x, 0, z); }

    public Vector3 RotateAbout(Vector3 axis, float angle)
    {
        return Matrix3.RotateAbout(axis, angle)*this;
    }

    public Vector3 RotateAboutX(float angle)
    {
        float cos=(float)Math.Cos(angle), sin=(float)Math.Sin(angle);

        return new Vector3(
            x,
            y*cos-z*sin,
            y*sin+z*cos);
    }
    public Vector3 RotateAboutY(float angle)
    {
        float cos=(float)Math.Cos(angle), sin=(float)Math.Sin(angle);

        return new Vector3(
            x*cos+z*sin,
            y,
            -x*sin+z*cos);
    }
    public Vector3 RotateAboutZ(float angle)
    {
        float cos=(float)Math.Cos(angle), sin=(float)Math.Sin(angle);

        return new Vector3(
            x*cos-y*sin,
            x*sin+y*cos,
            z);
    }
    public Vector3 MirrorAboutXY() { return new Vector3(x, y, -z); }
    public Vector3 MirrorAboutXZ() { return new Vector3(x, -y, z); }
    public Vector3 MirrorAboutYZ() { return new Vector3(-x, y, z); }
    #endregion

    #region Operators
    public static Vector3 operator+(Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) { return lhs.Add(rhs); }
    public static Vector3 operator-(Vector3 rhs) { return rhs.Scale(-1); }
    public static Vector3 operator-(Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) { return lhs.Add(rhs, -1); }
    public static Vector3 operator*(float lhs, Vector3 rhs) { return rhs.Scale(lhs); }
    public static Vector3 operator*(Vector3 lhs, float rhs) { return lhs.Scale(rhs); }
    public static Vector3 operator/(Vector3 lhs, float rhs) { return lhs.Scale(1/rhs); }
    public static Vector3 operator/(float lhs, Vector3 rhs) { return rhs.Reciprocal(lhs); }
    public static float operator*(Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) { return Dot(lhs, rhs); }
    public static Vector3 operator^(Vector3 lhs, Vector3 rhs) { return Cross(lhs, rhs); }
    public static Vector3 operator*(Vector3 lhs, Matrix3 rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Multiply(rhs);
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICloneable Members

    public Vector3 Clone() { return new Vector3(this); }

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return Clone();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<float> Members

    public IEnumerator<float> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return x;
        yield return y;
        yield return z;
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion


    #region IEquatable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Equality overrides from <see cref="System.Object"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare this with</param>
    /// <returns>False if object is a different type, otherwise it calls <code>Equals(Vector3)</code></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Vector3)
        {
            return Equals((Vector3)obj);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for equality among <see cref="Vector3"/> classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The other <see cref="Vector3"/> to compare it to</param>
    /// <returns>True if equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(Vector3 other)
    {
        return x.Equals(other.x)
            &&y.Equals(other.y)
            &&z.Equals(other.z);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the hash code for the <see cref="Vector3"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The int hash value</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((17*23+x.GetHashCode())*23+y.GetHashCode())*23+z.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IFormattable Members
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString("G");
    }
    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        return ToString(format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
    }
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return string.Format("({0},{1},{2})",
            x.ToString(format, formatProvider),
            y.ToString(format, formatProvider),
            z.ToString(format, formatProvider));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Triangles
    public static float TriangleArea(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c)
    {
        Vector3 u=b-a, v=c-a;
        Vector3 k=Vector3.Cross(u, v);
        return k.Magnitude/2;
    }

    public static Vector3 TriangleNormal(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c)
    {
        Vector3 u=b-a, v=c-a;
        return Vector3.Cross(u, v).Normalized();
    }

    #endregion


    #region IParsable Members

    public void FromString(string description)
    {
        // "(X,Y,Z)" => (X,Y,Z)
        description=description.Trim('(', ')');
        var parts=description.Split(',');
        if (parts.Length==3)
        {
            float new_x=0, new_y=0, new_z=0;
            if (!float.TryParse(parts[0].Trim(), out new_x))
            {
                new_x=x;
            }
            if (!float.TryParse(parts[1].Trim(), out new_y))
            {
                new_y=y;
            }
            if (!float.TryParse(parts[2].Trim(), out new_z))
            {
                new_z=z;
            }
            this=new Vector3(new_x, new_y, new_z);
        }
    }

    public float[] ToArray()
    {
        return new float[] { x, y, z };
    }


    #endregion

}
```

Some example usage here:

```
public TestVector()
{
    Vector3 A=new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
    Vector3[] array=new Vector3[100];
    array[0]=A;
    for (int i=1; i<100; i++)
    {                
        array[i]=2*array[i-1]+Vector3.Cross(array[i], Vector3.I);
        // or 2*array[i-1]+(array[i]^Vector3.I);
    }
    float Ax = A[0];
    float max_x=array.Max((v) => v.X);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
public static Vertex[] operator+(Vertex[] A, Vertex[] B)
{
    return new vertex[] { A.x+B.x, A.y+B.y, A.z+B.z };
}
```

but

```
return new vertex[] { A.x+B.x, A.y+B.y, A.z+B.z };
```

is not a valid expression since for `Vertex[] A` there is no `A.x`.

Quick lambda solution:

```
return A.Zip(B, (v1, v2) => new Vertex(v1.x+v2.x, v1.y+v2.y, v1.z+v2.z)).ToArray();
```

Whereas the latter `new Vertex()` expression could also be simplified if you overload the `+` operator of the `Vertex` object.

So, in no way is "Is c# mathematically illiterate/innumerate". Just a little bit of `System.Linq` needed to make it a nice expression.

This is basically component-wise vector addition implemented in C# with operator overloading. Also see http://www.dotnetperls.com/zip.

EDIT: Nope, in fact I was wrong. You can only overload operators from the enclosing class, so no direct overloads for a `Vertex[]` unless you declar `Vertex[]` as own wrapper class. But here is a complete, working code with some operator overloading and vector addition.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Vertex
{
   public float x,y,z;

    public Vertex(float _x, float _y,float  _z) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _y;
    }

    public static Vertex operator+(Vertex v1, Vertex v2)
    {
        return new Vertex(v1.x+v2.x, v1.y+v2.y, v1.z+v2.z);
    }

    public static Vertex[] AddVertices(Vertex[] A, Vertex[] B)
    {
        return A.Zip(B, (v1, v2) => v1 + v2).ToArray();
    }

    public override String ToString() { return string.Format("({0}, {1}, {2})",x,y,z);}
}


class Program
{
    const int some_small_int=2;
    static Vertex[] A=new Vertex[]{ new Vertex(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f),new Vertex(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)};
    static Vertex[] B=new Vertex[]{new Vertex(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f),new Vertex(10.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f)};

    static Vertex[] C= Vertex.AddVertices(A,B);


    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vertex Array A:");
        foreach(var vert in A) Console.WriteLine(vert);

        Console.WriteLine("Vertex Array B:");
        foreach(var vert in B) Console.WriteLine(vert);

        Console.WriteLine("Vertex Array C:");
        foreach(var vert in C) Console.WriteLine(vert);

        var vert1 = new Vertex(1,2,3);
        var vert2 = new Vertex(4,5,6);
        var vert3 = vert1 + vert2;

        Console.WriteLine("Vertex v1 + v2:" + vert3.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: See again for real working C# code.

Comment: After sleeping on this I am finding this compiles:       float [ ] Centroid ( Vertex [ ] v )
            {
            int Count = v . Count ( );
            Vertex s = new Vertex();
            foreach ( Vertex vv in v )
                {
                s += vv;
                }
            float [ ] V = new float [ 3 ];
            return V;
            }

Comment: public static Vertex operator+ ( Vertex a , Vertex b )
                {
                Vertex c = new Vertex();
                c . x = a . x + b . x;
                c . y = a . y + b . y;
                c . z = a . z + b . z;
                return c;
                }

Comment: ok. The 'wordy' solution.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand the issue.

The implementation of c# (=) assignment then (+) addition as two operators, not a single operator (=+) summation.

In c++ (=) is one token that is a unary operator that can be overloaded..

in c++
a=+b is shorthand for a=a+b

in c#

a=+b expands into a=a+b but it is not the equality operator that can be overloaded but the addition operator as a binary operator.

So the solution to overloading is to overload the plus, minus, multiplication, division, etc for the types required as binary operators, not unary operators.

Surprisingly, this seems to compile to compute the centroid of a Boxel Type, that consists of an array of edges, each edge has two vertices. I have yet to test the run time code but think it will work now.

```
        public static Vertex operator / ( Vertex a , int b )
            {
            Vertex c = new Vertex ( );
            c . x = a . x / b;
            c . y = a . y / b;
            c . z = a . z / b;
            return c;
            }
        public static Vertex operator + ( Vertex a , Vertex b )
            {
            Vertex c = new Vertex ( );
            c . x = a . x + b . x;
            c . y = a . y + b . y;
            c . z = a . z + b . z;
            return c;
            }



        Vertex NewCentroid ( Boxel B )
        {
        Vertex C = new Vertex();

        C = NewCentroid ( B . E );

        return C;
        }
    Vertex NewCentroid ( Edge [ ] E )
        {
        Vertex C = new Vertex ( ){0.0,0.0,0.0};

        foreach ( Edge e in E )
            {
            C **+** = NewCentroid ( e );
            }

        return C;
        }
    Vertex NewCentroid ( Edge e )
        {
        Vertex C = new Vertex ( );
        C = NewCentroid ( e . V0 , e . V1 );
        return C;
        }
    Vertex NewCentroid ( Vertex v0 , Vertex v1 )
        {
        Vertex C = new Vertex ( );

        C = v0 **+** v1;
        C =**/** 2.0;
        return C;
        }
```

Correct me if I am wrong. I'm old and decrepit in my programming ways.

[Cap Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) is the big greek letter usually taken as summation from downstairs subscript to upstairs superscript.

Now being symbol minded and old and decrepit I am happier.

I retract my accusation about c# being mathematically innumerate/illiterate.